# Using XPath to parse HTML NFL.com

Tags: php, html, xpath

http://www.nfl.com/widget/gc/2011/tabs/cat-post-boxscore?gameId=2012093000

I am looking to scrape the data from pages like the link above (that is, game level NFL data).

NFL.com has a handy JSON API that makes a lot of this data accessible. That is, for games 2010 and later. For earlier games, I am going to have to parse the HTML of pages similar to the one above.

I've been trying to scrape this using Xpath.  However, I have found it difficult to differentiate between the table headers which are table rows of class "thd2" and the data which are tables rows of class "tbdy1"

If anyone knows how to loop through this data and extract the data, the table headers and get them into an array, I'd like to see your approach!

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.nfl.com/widget/gc/2011/tabs/cat-post-boxscore?gameId=2012093000');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');

$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tables = $xpath->query('//table[1]/tbody/td');
var_dump($tables);
```

Comment: Please clarify how you found it *difficult to to differentiate between the table headers which are table rows of class "thd2" and the data which are tables rows of class "tbdy1"*. Also, please show what you have tried and where the issues are. Also show what you expect the final array to look like.

Comment: Also note the ToS, stating *Systematic retrieval of data or other content from the Services, whether to create or compile, directly or indirectly, a collection, compilation, database or directory, is prohibited absent our express prior written consent.* Additional terms in the section about "Modular Content".

Comment: Here is some basic code just accessing td's in the first table... obviously var-dump doesnt show anything in terms of data because its ouputting DOMElements... the real issue for me is that the tbdy1 tags are variable (that is there could be two players who played quarterback in a game and are both listed under "Passing" which is the first thd2 tag)... since those entries are variable, how can I ensure I access all of the tbdy1 tags?  Also, the array I'm looking to output will look like this Array([Passing]->(Tom Brady, "",etc),[CP/AT]->(##/##,##/##,##/##)) (basically the thd2's would be keys)

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project, not aggregating a substantial amount of data.

Comment: Check http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html

Comment: @Gordon, can you put that as an answer, so this question can be categorized as answered?

Comment: @LarsH but it doesnt answer the question.